# DataGrid empty after load Application

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I Have DataGrid that contains DataBase table Information (access if it's matter).

Until now I had perfect datagrid work's with database but with buttons( Show, Add, Delete and Edit), but now, I want to delete the buttons and do all these functions with only the dataGrid.

When I do the show button without the clicking ( automatically when the wpf loading ) It show the data table but when I try to set header column it show me that the DataGrid is null (when These dataGrid show's the table from the data base with the right information). I would like to get help with this issue. Thank's.

The code :

```
try
{
    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.OpenConnectionWithDB();
    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.LoadDataFromDB(DictionaryUtilsDB.dictioneary[DictionaryUtilsDB.CommendTypes.ShowIkuns]);
    dataGridIkuns.ItemsSource = DataBaseIkuns.Instance.dt.DefaultView;
    // ---------------------- Until here it work's perfect - loading the table from the data base with the origin header column 

    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.SetNameOnHeaderColumn(dataGridIkuns); // here it fall.
    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.CloseConnectionWithDB();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

internal void SetNameOnHeaderColumn(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGridIkuns)
{
    dataGridIkuns.Columns[0].Header = "x"; // Fall because DataGridIkuns colomn count is 0.
    dataGridIkuns.Columns[1].Header = "y";
}
```

The error : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index

When I click "Show" button it do this exactly function and it work's perfect. But when I do it when the wpf appliaction load it wrong. Why?

By the way another question, if anyone know guide for work's with the dataGrid (add,remove and edit) without buttons only with keyboard editing) I would very happy to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are letting the grid auto-generate columns for you, then chances are that the columns have not been populated yet.  Column auto-population does not necessarily happen instantaneously upon setting the `ItemsSource`; it may be deferred either because the grid has never been measured, or because it has no data items yet.

You can try deferring the call to `SetNameOnHeaderColumn` until later by scheduling it on the `Dispatcher` using `BeginInvoke` with `DispatcherPriority.Loaded`:

```
try
{
    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.OpenConnectionWithDB();
    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.LoadDataFromDB(/* ... */);

    var view = DataBaseIkuns.Instance.dt.DefaultView;

    dataGridIkuns.ItemsSource = view;

    dataGridIkuns.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
        new Action(
            () =>
            {
                if (dataGridIkuns.ItemsSource == view)
                    SetNameOnHeaderColumn(dataGridIkuns);
            }));

    DataBaseIkuns.Instance.CloseConnectionWithDB();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

---

Since you asked, here are some standard shortcuts that should work with the `DataGrid`:

- `Tab/Shift+Tab` - Go to next/prev cell on current row, or wrap around to next/prev row
- `Left/Right` - Go to prev/next cell on current row **only**
- `Up/Down` - Go to prev/next row
- `F2` - Edit selected cell
- `F4` - Open cell editor drop-down (once editing, if applicable)
- `Esc` - Cancel edit
- `Del` - Delete current row (when not editing a cell)
- `Home/End` - Jump to first/last cell in row
- `Ctrl+Home/Ctrl+End` - Jump to first/last row in grid
- `PgUp/PgDn` - Jump up/down one "page" in the view
- `Enter/Shift+Enter` - Commit current cell if editing, then jump to same column in next/prev row

I am not aware of any shortcut to insert a new row or to jump to the new row placeholder.

Comment: Would you help me to do what you just writted ? I haven't really understand

Comment: Your shortcut isn't working.. for example f2 it really editted the table but it doesn't edit the data base.

Comment: The data grid doesn't know anything about your database.